# How to prevent html list menu items from refreshing after assigning permission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

Please I am assigning user permission based on user type read from session data in Node.js and the hide html li elements based on the type of user. It seems to work but the behaviour it awful in the sense that. Whenever I load a page, all the menu items refresh/ loads again before they are hidden. How do I prevent this behaviour. It there something I have doing wrong or the approach is just not good. I have reference the client-side code on each page within the application
This is my code for the client side

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var CheckPermission = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/permission';
    $.get(CheckPermission, function (data) {
        if (data == 'Student') {
            $("#Offer").find("#shareitem").show();
            $("#Offer").find("#offeritem").hide();
            $("#Offer").find("#returnitem").hide();
            $("#Offer").find("#recallitem").hide();
            $("#Offer").find("#renewitem").hide();
            $("#Offer").find("#guestoffer").hide();
            $("#Offer").find("#manageoffers").hide();
            $("#Overview").hide();
            $("#WithHolding").hide();

        } else if (data == 'Admin') {

            $("#Offer").find("#shareitem").hide();
            $("#Discover").hide();

        } else if (data == 'Teacher') {
            $("#Offer").find("#shareitem").hide();
            $("#Discover").hide();
        } else {
            $("#Offer").hide();
            $("#Discover").hide();
            $("#Overview").hide();
            $("#WithHolding").hide();
            $("#myAccount").hide();
            $("#Message").hide();

        }
    })
});
```

This is my code on the server side

```
outer.get('/permission',function(req,res) {   
    if (req.user)
    {
        var UserType = req.user.UserType;
        switch (UserType) {
            case "Admin":
                if ((req.isAuthenticated()) && (req.user.UserType == 'Admin')) {
                    res.send(UserType)
                }
                break;
            case "Student":
                if ((req.isAuthenticated()) && (req.user.UserType == 'Student')) {
                    res.send(UserType)
                }
                break;
            case "Teacher":
                if ((req.isAuthenticated()) && ((req.user.UserType == 'Admin') || (req.user.UserType == 'Professor'))) {
                    res.send(UserType)
                }
                break;
            default :
                if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
                    res.send(UserType)
                }
        }
    }else{
        res.send('undefined')
    }
});
```

// This is my Navbar which contains the menus and it is called or references on each page through out the application

```
    <script src="/javascript/ClientJs/HideMenus.js"></script>
//This my Javascript file which contains the permission instructions(client side)

<nav id="nav"class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="z-index: 10;">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="brand" href="/"><%=__('Borrowing Sys')%></a>

            <div class="nav-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="true">
                <ul id="menu"class="nav">
                    <li id="home"><a href="/"><%=__('Home')%></a></li>
                    <li id="Offer" class="dropdown">
                        <a href="/#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><%=__('Offer')%><span
                                    class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li id="offeritem"><a href="/itemoffers"><%=__('Offer Item')%></a></li>
                            <li id="recallitem"><a href="/recallitem"><%=__('Recall Item')%></a></li>
                            <li id="renewitem"><a href="/renewitem"><%=__('Renew Item')%></a></li>
                            <li id="returnitem"><a href="/returnitem"><%=__('Return Item')%></a></li>
                            <li id="odivider"class="divider"></li>
                            <li id="guestoffer"><a href="/guestitemoffers"><%=__('Guest Offer')%></a></li>
                            <li id="shareitem"><a href="/shareitem"><%=__('Share Item')%></a></li>
                            <li id="manageoffers"><a href="/manage/manageoffers"><%=__('Manage Offers')%></a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="Discover"class="dropdown">
                        <a href="/#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><%=__('Discover Items')%><span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="/discoverymap"><%=__('Discovery Map')%></a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Asktobuy"><%=__('Send a Request')%></a></li>
                            <li><a href="/shareditems/availableoffer"><%=__('Available Items')%></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li id="Message" class="dropdown">
                        <a href="/#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><%=__('Messages')%><span
                                    class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="/messages"><%=__('Private Messages')%></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li id="Overview"class="dropdown">
                        <a href="/#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><%=__('System Overview')%><span
                                    class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="/analysis"><%=__('Data Analysis')%></a></li>
                            <li><a href="/activitylog"><%=__('User Activity Logs')%></a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="/manage/removeoffers"><%=__('Remove Offers')%></a></li>
                            <li><a href="/checkrequest"><%=__('Students Request')%></a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="myAccount" class="dropdown">
                        <a href="/#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><%=__('My Account')%><span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li id="youroffers"><a href="/offers/myoffers"><%=__('Your Offers')%></a></li>
                            <li id="reservations"><a href="/checkreservations"><%=__('Reservations')%></a></li>
                            <li id="divider"class="divider"></li>
                            <li id="profile"><a href="/user"><%=__('My Profile')%></a></li>
                            <li id="invite"><a href="/InviteFriend"><%=__('Invite Friend')%></a></li>
                            <li ><a href="/logout"><%=__('Log out')%></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <!-- add search form -->
                <div id="WithHolding" class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
                    <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="<%=__('Student ID')%>" Id="SearchStudent" name="SearchStudent">
                            <button id="Search" name="Search" class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><%=__('Check Clearance')%>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
This is a typical example of how i have referenced the NavBar on all pages. This is the overall structure of the design



     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <% include ./MyLayout/header %>
    <body>
    <% include ./MyLayout/navbar %>
    <script src="/javascript/ClientJs/RenewItem.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div id="content" class="span12">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <form class="form-horizontal span12" method="post" action="RenewItems">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend><%=__('Renew Item')%>
                                <h6 style="color: #006dcc"><%=__('Extend/Renew item given to student')%></h6>
                            </legend>
                            <br>
                            <% if(SuccessMessage.length>0){ %>
                            <div class="row-fluid status-bar">
                                <div class="span12">
                                    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" id="alertmessage" role="alert">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span
                                                    aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                        <strong><%=__('Success !')%></strong><%= SuccessMessage %>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <% } %>
                            <% if(ErrorMessage.length>0){ %>
                            <div class="row-fluid status-bar">
                                <div class="span12">
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" id="alertmessage" role="alert">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span
                                                    aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                        <strong><%=__('Error!')%></strong> <%= ErrorMessage %>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <% } %>
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <div class="span8">
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                        <label for="BookingNo" class="control-label"><%=__('Booking Number:')%></label>

                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input id="BookingNumber" name="BookingNumber" type="text" value="" required=""
                                                   title="<%=__('Please enter Booking number for the transaction')%>"
                                                   placeholder="<%=__('Booking Number')%>">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                        <label for="ItemName" class="control-label"><%=__('Item Name:')%></label>

                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input type="text" id="ItemName" name="ItemName" value="" required=""
                                                   title="<%=__('Please enter Item Name')%>" placeholder="<%=__('Item Name')%>">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                        <label for="StudentID" class="control-label"><%=__('Student/Guest ID:')%></label>

                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input id="StudentID" name="StudentID" type="text" value="" readonly required=""
                                                   title="<%=__('Please enter student matriculation ID')%>" placeholder="<%=__('Matriculation Number/Guest ID')%>">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="control-group">
                                        <label for="ItemNumber" class="control-label"><%=__('Item Number:')%></label>

                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input id="ItemNumber" name="ItemNumber" type="text" value="" readonly
                                                   required="" title="<%=__('Please enter Item Number')%>" placeholder="<%=__('Item Number')%>">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                        <label for="EmailID" class="control-label"><%=__('Student/Guest Email ID:')%></label>

                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input type="text" id="StudentEmail" name="StudentEmail" value=""
                                                   placeholder="<%=__('Student/Guest Email')%>" readonly required=""
                                                   title="<%=__('Student/Guest Email ID cannot be empty')%>">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                        <label for="ReturnDate" class="control-label"><%=__('Old Return Date:')%></label>

                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input id="OldReturnDate" name="OldReturnDate" type="text" value="" readonly
                                                 placeholder="<%=__('DD-MM-YYYY')%>"  required="" title="<%=__('Please search for item')%>">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                        <label for="Remarks" class="control-label"><%=__('Duration:')%></label>

                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <select Id="Duration" name="Duration" class="form-control">
                                                <option value="1 week"><%=__('1 week')%></option>
                                                <option value="2 weeks"><%=__('2 weeks')%></option>
                                                <option value="3 weeks"><%=__('3 weeks')%></option>
                                                <option value="4 weeks"><%=__('4 weeks')%></option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                        <label for="ReturnDate" class="control-label"><%=__('New Return Date:')%></label>

                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input id="ReturnDate" name="ReturnDate" type="text" value="" placeholder="<%=__('DD-MM-YYYY')%>"
                                                    readonly required="" title="<%=__('Please specify duration of extension')%>">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                        <label for="Remarks" class="control-label"><%=__('Remarks:')%></label>

                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <textarea id="Remarks" name="Remarks" style="width: 70%;" rows="4" required=""
                                                      title="<%=__('Any remarks regarding the renewal of an item')%>"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>

                        <div class="form-actions">
                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default"><%=__('Cancel')%></button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><%=__('Renew')%></button>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    <% include ./MyLayout/footer_bottom%>
    </html>
```

Comment: might be more sightly to hide them all from css and un-hide as needed.

Comment: You are noticing this because of the delay in getting the response from the server.

Answer (score 2):

What about hiding everything first. Suppose your menu items are wrapped in a `div` or if menu items are in a `OL/UL`, you can set it up to hide on loading of page:

```
.menu-wrapper{
    display:none;
}


$(document).ready(function () {

    var CheckPermission = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/permission';
    $.get(CheckPermission, function (data) {
        //your stuff
    }).always(function(){
        $(".menu-wrapper").show();//this will toggle display:none
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried your approach but I still get same behaviour

Comment: If you post some of the HTML as well, we may be able to help you better.

Answer (score 1):

You are noticing this because of the delay in getting the response from the server.

```
All Menus Loaded First > Wait Few Seconds > Server Responds > Hide Menus
```

To avoid this, hiding menus during initial loading and showing them once you get the response will be the correct approach.

BTW, I will not prefer to show and hide menu items in the client side. The best option will be to get the list of allowed menu items from the server and rendering in the client side.

Please remember, an user can change the CSS styles to see the hidden menu and he could do operations that are not allowed, unless your server validates each request.

Change your html to render the menus in hidden mode, by adding the css class.

```
.menu-wrapper {
    display:none;
}

<ul id="menu" class="nav">
    <li id="home"class="hidden-menu"><a href="/"><%=__('Home')%></a></li>
    <li id="Offer" class="dropdown menu-wrapper">
    </li>
    <li id="Discover" class="dropdown menu-wrapper">
    </li>
    <li id="Message" class="dropdown menu-wrapper">
    </li>
    <li id="Overview" class="dropdown menu-wrapper">
    </li>
    <li id="myAccount" class="dropdown menu-wrapper">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then after you get the permissions from the server, enable the nodes.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var CheckPermission = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/permission';
  $.get(CheckPermission, function (data) {
    // If the menu should be shown then remove the css class
    if(data === 'Admin') {
      $("#Discover").removeClass('hidden-menu');  
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your clue and advice.  It tried to hide all first at document ready before hitting the database for the permission but it still behaves that way. Also, I validating the permission at the server-side as well using this `router.get('/recallitem/', checkloggedIn.isAdmin,function (req, res) {
    res.render('RecallItem', { ErrorMessage: req.flash('ValidationError')});
});`

Comment: `isAdminLoggedIn: function (req, res, next) {
        // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on
        if ((req.isAuthenticated()) && (req.user.UserType=='Admin'))
        {
            return next();
        }else{
            // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
            req.flash('ValidationError',res.__('Sorry,you do not have enough privileges to access this page'));
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    },`

Comment: I have posted more details about the structure. Thank you for your support